# unable to start hortonworks ambari metrics collector

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have installed HDP on a 12 node cluster. I used the Hortonworks automated ambari install. Everything is working EXCEPT the Ambari Metrics Collector. This is my third time trying this install, having attempted to customize the distribution locations of some of the components. Each time I was getting errors that I couldn't isolate so I did a reformat of the machines and tried again, each time simplifying things. This last time I made no alterations except for the location of the Hive and Oozie databases. But I keep having the same problem with the Metrics collector not starting. I have run out of ideas.
From the error file at /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-376.txt:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/AMBARI_METRICS/0.1.0/package/scripts/metrics_collector.py", line 131, in <module>
    AmsCollector().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
                      ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_jinja2/environment.py", line 891, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "<template>", line 5, in top-level template code
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2028' in position 1341: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am not sure if it is hanging trying to read the u/'u2028' character in a Template that I can't find, or is it something else?
I also see the following in the StdOut  at /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-376.txt:

```
      ...
2016-04-06 06:55:20,967 - Generating config: /etc/ambari-metrics-collector/conf/ams-site.xml
2016-04-06 06:55:20,968 - File['/etc/ambari-metrics-collector/conf/ams-site.xml'] {'owner': 'ams', 'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None, 'encoding': 'UTF-8'}
```

Here I wonder why this file is not with the rest of the config files located at /etc/hadoop/conf/ or /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/

I feel like this HAS to be a simple mistake in my settings because I have had a cluster running just fine on virtual machines using the automated install for months. his install, though larger, is on bare metal machines of larger capacity.
Is there somewhere else I should be looking for answers?
Thanks for any help or direction.

Oh yes,.. I am also getting three connection errors:

```
FQDN:61310    Connection failed [errno 111] Connection refused
0.0.0.0:6188   Connection failed [errno 111] Connection refused
FQDN:61181   Connection failed [errno 111] Connection refused
```

I got Ambari metrics to run, at least temprarily,..  by changing it's mode to distributed from embedded. Insodoing, as I saved configuration changes, new recommendations were offered which switched the value of hbase_regionserver_heaqpsize and metrics_collector_heapsize several times. After about three or four rounds of changing the values I choose Proceed Anyways and so far it is working.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I managed to get it to work but I am uncertain why, so, I would say I didn't solve this, just managed it. As I mentioned, each time I made a change to the recommended settings, new recommendations appeared. I simply kept doing this until one time when no new recommendations appeared and ambari metrics continued to function. I can't remember how many rounds of adjustments it took but there were several, to be sure.  Doesn't say much for my problem solving skills but it supports my claim to be determined,...